# Remove and insert drop down list values

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have a couple of dropdown lists like this

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Update_ddls" AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddl1" />

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl2" />
```

Which are populated by a column in my db like this

```
query.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM locations"

DataTable = New DataTable()
DataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(query)
DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)

If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    ddl1.DataSource = DataTable.DefaultView
    ddl1.DataTextField = "location"
    ddl1.DataValueField = "location"
    ddl1.DataBind()
    ddl1.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select...", "Select..."))
End If
```

I also have a function called `Update_ddls` which runs `OnSelectedIndexChanged` that looks like this

```
ddl2.Items.Remove(ddl2.Items.FindByValue(ddl1.SelectedValue.ToString()))
```

Which removes the selected item in ddl1 from the second dropdown but if I keep changing the `ddl1` item then `ddl2` won't have any items left in it.

Is there a way to re-add the previously deleted items in the `Update_dlls` function without re-databinding because if I re-databind I lose the selected item in the `ddl`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store `SelectedValue` in some `variable` before `rebinding` the dropdownlist and then simply remove the value from dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

You could re-databind ddl2 in your OnSelectedIndexChanged handler for ddl1 and then remove the selectedValue from ddl1 after the fact.